# How to get current displayed activity from static ASyncTask?

Tags: android

I'm currently having a hard time with a static ASyncTask reporting its result via a snackbar message.

Here's the top of the ASyntask:

```
private static class PushSettingsToDevice extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {
    private View rootView;
    private PushSettingsToDevice(View rootView){this.rootView = rootView;}
```

And here's the end:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        try{
            Log.d(TAG, "pushSettings Finished.");
            Snackbar.make(rootView, MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_schedule_menu_settings_applied), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

To display the snackBar, I need a reference to a View (rootView in my exemple), but by doing so, I reference a view from a static class, and create a memory leak.

How can I display the snackBar on any view the user is currently seeing? In other words, how can I retrieve from my static ASyncTask the Activity currently displayed to the user, and then a view within this Activity?

Comment: Still pass in the view, but use a `WeakReference` to store them so that if the view is destroyed, the weak reference will be as well, so there won't be any memory leaks

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the concept of WeakReference. You just made my life a whole lot easier! Thanks for solving this problem, and many other I would have had in the future!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by [jackz314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8170714/jackz314)

Here's the new code:

```
private static class PushSettingsToDevice extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {
    private WeakReference<View> rootView;

    private PushSettingsToDevice(View rootView, boolean debug_mode){this.rootView = new WeakReference<>(rootView);}
```

And the end:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        try{
            Log.d(TAG, "pushSettings Finished.");
            if(rootView != null){
                Snackbar.make(rootView.get(), MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_schedule_menu_settings_applied), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```